# Statistical test that compare observed events with expeected

Tags: statistical-significance

Could anyone enlighten me on what will be the appropriate statistics to test whether a series of events is significantly different from the expected or not.

For example, there is a pool of infinitive balls, and one can use a basket to retrieve balls from the pool. If the basket is functioning well, each time it should get an average of 10 balls (sd = 3). But if it has some problems, the number might be less or more.

In this case, if I did 5 retrievals, and I observe 3, 5, 10, 10, 2 balls, how can I tell if the basket functions well or not?

Comment: If "functions well" means it needs to get 10 balls, then obviously it isn't functioning well.  If, on the other hand, "functions well" means it always gets *some* balls, then it is functioning well.  This shows that *you need to defined what "functions well" might mean for your application* before statistics can help you determine (from data) whether the process functions well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. "functions well" what I intend to say is that on average 10 balls (SD = 3) should be in the basket for each retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Several options to consider among others:

Z-test can be used to test whether the mean is 10 assuming the sd is 3. The standard error of the mean is $3/\sqrt{5}$.
The sample mean (6) is 3 standard errors below 10. A mean this far away from 10 only happens about once or twice in a thousand times.
There is moderately strong evidence that the mean is not 10 assuming the distribution is normal and the sd. is 3. I would only conclude that either one of the assumptions is false or the mean is not 10.

t-test can be used to test whether the mean is 10 assuming the data are normal. The p-value is about 0.08 so not much evidence against the null hypothesis that the mean is 10.

Chi-square test can be used to test whether the variance is 3^2. The statistic won't have a chi-square distribution unless the data are normal. But, a large sample test can be made using the mean and variance of $s^2$ found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance).
Observed variance of 14.5 is not very far from hypothesized variance of 3^2 in any case.

If you think the counts have a specific distribution such as the Poisson distribution with mean and variance 10, then you can directly test whether the mean is 10. A sample mean of 6 only happens about once or twice in a thousand times for samples with n=5 from the Poisson distribution with mean 10.